# Has either Batman's or Superman's identity been accidentally revealed by someone in the comics?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, superman, secret-identity

In the recent animated movie *Batman: The Long Halloween Part 1*, Selina Kyle accidentally calls Batman Bruce, and thereby revealing his identity to Alberto Falcone (this is obviously different from the comics). Indeed Alberto dies within the next few seconds but Batman's identity was for a moment revealed by Selina's stupidity.

The second instance is from *Justice League* (both Joss Whedon's and Synder's versions). When Superman is resurrected using the Mother box, he attacks the Justice League and Lois arrives on time to stop him:

> **Lois Lane**: Clark! Clark!
>
> **Military Officer**: Whoa, whoa! Hold your fire, hold your fire!
>
> [Lois steps in front of Batman. Clark's heat vision deactivates.]
>
> **Lois Lane**: Clark... Please. Please. Please. Just go. Let's go.
>
> [Clark leans into the hug, then takes off with Lois in his arms.]
>  <sub>*Justice League : The Snyder cut (2021)*</sub>

> [Before Superman can crush Batman's chin, Alfred arrive with "the big
> guns": Lois Lane. She steps out of the limousine and speaks to
> Superman]
>
> Lois Lane: Clark? Clark. Please... Please. Please, just go. Yeah?
> Let's go.
>  <sub>*Justice League (2017)*</sub>

Although in this instance, we do not know if someone actually made the Clark Kent - Superman connection.

There have been quite a few instances where super villains have discovered Batman and Superman's secret identities either by deduction, educated guess or by sheer luck. However in both instances mentioned above, either emotions (and/or stupidity) made someone reveal Batman and Superman's secret identity.

I don't remember seeing anything like this in the comics but, have there been such instances when Batman and/or Superman's identities have been mistakenly revealed?

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/4SbNtrgmXvHoHmEa6

Comment: @Valorum As far as I'm aware that isn't real and is just a dream sequence Superman is having. (For reference to other readers as I'm sure you're aware of that).

Comment: "Accidently" does not necessarily equal "stupidity"

Comment: Does a "deleted scene" count? https://youtu.be/0Y8iRvQdSGA?t=180

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Huntress calls Batman Bruce in *Injustice: Gods Among Us Vol. 1* Issue 25 when surrounded by other members of the Insurgency without knowing that others around the table don't know this.

[image: Huntress and Bruce are arguing, close up on their faces. Huntress: "Being sanctimonious and arrogant doesn't make you right, Bruce!"] [image: They carry on arguing. Huntress: "There are people in this room who don't know your secret identity, aren't there?"]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Only a few panels later this forced Bruce's hand to take off his cowl and reveal to everyone at the table who he is.

[image: Batman realises he has no other option than to reveal to the group who he is and takes off his cowl] [image: Now cowl-less the group react in surprise to who he is]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Whilst Huntress does so accidentally her doing so didn't directly cause others to find out about his secret identity but leads to a short chain of events where it is revealed.

Comment: I never realized that the answer was from the *Injustice* universe. I even forgot this happened :( been a long long time since I read those

Comment: @Shreedhar never too late to read the *Injustice* comics for the nth time I say :)

Answer (score 24):

Batman OR Superman?  How about Batman AND Superman blundering into a secret identity revelation!

*Superman* #76 (1952) has the never-revealed tale of how Superman and Batman became the world's finest team.  The following two pages explain how the two inadvertent roommates completely stumble on to each other's staggering secrets:
[image]

[image]

The hardest suspension of disbelief is just why millionaire Bruce Wayne is having such an economy-class vacation where the boat can just force a roomie on him.

Comment: *force a roomie on him* - It's the other way round. Clark booked, or lucked into, a private cabin. Bruce (is his reason given in the story?) needed to travel on that ship but had no reservation, so used his wealth and influence to impose on the purser and on some random passenger. Clark, as Clark, has no wealth nor influence with which to object.

Comment: A.I. Breveleri - There ain't a lot of preliminary space explaining the two heroes being on the ship.  Three panels show Batman and Robin finishing a big case against a crime syndicate and deciding some R&R is needed.  Dick Grayson goes to visit "distant relatives" and Bruce Wayne thinks a coastal cruise is just the thing for a real vacation.  Meanwhile, Clark Kent is likewise ready to depart on his vacation days aboard the same ship.  Mostly it seems the good ship "Varania" is guilty of some serious overbooking.

Comment: Somehow, I think that would-be supervillain's going to regret using an asbestos suit to try to steal diamonds, even if he hadn't had the bad luck to be doing it right next to a ship with both Batman and Superman on board.

Comment: Ah yes, my ASBESTOS SUIT will protect me!

Answer (score 18):

Way back in Adventure 290 (11-61) Ma Kent lets it slip when a juvenile delinquent named Tom Tanner is impersonating Clark for reasons of his own.  Superboy let the impersonation go because his robots were down and he expected to be home first.[image]

Answer (score 17):

In ***[Superboy Vol 4 #61](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superboy_Vol_4_61)***, Superman's secret identity was revealed to the post-Crisis Superboy, [Kon-El/Connor Kent](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Kon-El_(New_Earth)), when the Jonathan Kent of an alternate reality addressed the Superboy of that world as "Clark" right in front of him.

Since Kon-El looked physically identical to the Superboy of his world (aside from having a different haircut), Jonathan mistakenly assumed he was another version of Clark, and thought it was safe to speak freely in front of him.

However, Kon-El was actually a clone, and didn't yet know that the versions of Clark and Superman he was acquainted with in his own reality were one and the same. In fact, he didn't even know that Superman had a secret identity back then (he didn't have one himself at the time).

[image]

[image]